# Visual Studio custom tooltip on variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In my C++ code in a multilingual project I have a function that returns a const wchar_t* by ID.

```
const wchar_t* s(int id);
```

This function returns a string from the default english pack, or a translated string from a possibly loaded DLL that contains strings.

The default english pack is simply a .h file with the strings as an array, e.g.

```
Line 1   const wchar_t* strings[] = {L"",L"OK",
Line 2    L"No",
Line 3    L"Yes",
...
```

this way I can, when I have e.g. s(122), to go to line 122 in that .h file and see the related string.

Now, is there a custom VS extension or a way for me to build one that would do that for me when I put the mouse over that s(...) function?

I can of course feed that feature a more structured document (such as a XML or json) with the string list.